# finding a value in multi-values column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have 2 tables as following:

[image: Original tables look like this]

Tam trying to get the department name of each employee (DepName column in table Emp table) from Dep table:

[image: To be like]

I have written this query:

```
update Emp
 set DepName= (
 select DepName
 from Dep
where array_to_string(EmpID, ',') like EmpID
);
```

It did not update the table Emp with the requested information, although I haven't got any error. Any help?

Comment: data type of EmpID of dep table please

Comment: mysql or postgresql ???  is not the same ...

Comment: It is character varying[].

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry. I am using postgresql.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Duplicating information in a relational database is not a good idea to begin with. It would be better to create a view that returns that information. Storing multiple values in a single column is already bad database design, but then duplicating that _again_ is evenworse

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. I know it would be better to do so but I need to collect info as much as I can from all tables in one table in order to export it and work with it in java to build my system. This is an easy example of the problem itself to make easy to follow for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
update emp
    set dept = d.depname
    from dep
    where emp.empid = any (dep.empid);
```

Having pointed that out, you *should not* do this.  Instead, I would suggest that you have a proper link to the department table and use `join` to bring in the department name.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert id int to character varying array  data type and then use contains operator with table dept and update as usual

```
    UPDATE emp  t1
    SET dept = dname
   from  dept t2
   where  t2.eid @> concat(concat('{',(t1.id::text)),'}') ::varchar[]
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e5c24b26b3479b68adf0b17c2050f715

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ text
LINE 6:   where d.EmpID like concat('%', CONCAT(Emp.EmpID, '%'))
                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 113

Comment: I have got this error: ERROR:  relation "t1" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE  t1
                ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 9 
I am using Postgres /pgadmin. All my tables are under a schema called osmm.

Comment: @Maya i given you fiddle link where i showed you this works

Comment: eid is varchar in your table however it is a character varying[] in mine. Any more suggestions in this case?

Comment: @Maya https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2437d7b8d229e4d49b8f73db2212fd37 check this link i am updating it character varing data type and it works

Comment: Excellent but still not an array. You are using character varying not character varying[] which I have got on my table.

Comment: @Maya  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e5c24b26b3479b68adf0b17c2050f715 check it updated answer